# Pre-Allocating Single Cell's Memory

Tags: matlab, dynamic-memory-allocation, cell-array

I am writing a code and would like to know how to pre-allocate the memory for a single cell. I understand that one can easily pre-allocate an array of cells, but this isn't what I'm looking for.

My code follows the following logic:

```matlab
for i = 1:numel(k)
    R{i} = % Some 4x4 matrix That changes each iteration
end

R = blkdiag(R{:});
```

The goal here is to build a comma-separated list of an arbitrary amount of matrices, say:

```
R = {A,B,C,D,E,...}
```

Such that `blkdiag` will return the following:

```
R = [A 0 0...
     0 B 0...
     0 0 C...
     ...     ]
```

The code I have right now works fine, I'd just like to know how to pre-allocate memory for this case such that it runs faster if I had an awful lot of matrices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocate-memory-for-a-cell-array.html

Comment: @AlecDonaldMather Unfortunately this doesn't since this creates nxm cells, whereas I only require one cell. I was wondering if there was a way to allocate the size of that one cell.

Comment: Do you mean allocate the size of the cell as in, the amount of memory in Bytes or something?

Comment: @AlecDonaldMather Since I have a loop that will consistently add another matrix to the cell, it will have to resize it on every iteration, similar to with a regular array. This is in order to decrease the computation time by already having it sized properly. So if I were to need 500 matrices, the cell would be shaped to accept 500 inputs before the loop begins.

Comment: Can you not just preallocate it with matricies that are all prefilled with `0`?

Comment: @AlecDonaldMather Turns out the code I wrote actually built an array of cells which wasn't what I thought it was doing, so I think I see where there was confusion between us. Turns out I could pre-allocate just the cell array instead of just a single cell which was my initial understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a matrix into a cell array doesn't cause the cell array to be resized, if your cell array was preallocated. `R = cell(numel(k),1)` will preallocate the cell array. Each element of this array is a reference to an array (or arbitrary type, could be a numeric array, another cell array, a struct array, an array of custom objects, doesn't matter).

When the cell array is first created, each cell contains an empty matrix, `[]`. Replacing this matrix just changes the reference stored in the cell array to point to a different array. `R{3} = x` doesn't reallocate memory, it only changes the reference in `R{3}` to now point to whatever matrix was stored in the variable `x`.

On the other hand, if you want to add values to the array stored in `R{3}`, you should preallocate that array:

```matlab
    R{3} = zeros(5,1); % preallocate the array pointed to by R{3}
    for ii=1:5
       R{3}(ii) = ii;
    end
```

Comment: I think I initially got confused and thought that the individual cell would have a culmination of my n matrices. As it turns out, it actually built an array of cells. I think I just confused myself with what MATLAB was actually doing. Since I was expecting there to be a comma-separated list or something.